# Cursor inside Entity after selection in draft-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm struggling making entities style work the way I would like to using draft-js. I'm adding styled entities to my input by selecting items in an autocomplete component. When I select one, it works, but the caret stays inside the entity until i add another character. Is there a way to move the caret after the actual entity without adding a space ?

I am using a library called `draft-js-autocomplete`, I don't mind making a pull request if necessary.

To illustrate:

[image: Autocomplete selection]
[image: After the selection]

Comment: some code would help to understand what's happening.

Comment: why don't you use a decorator for the highlight rather than an entity?

Comment: Here is the code example : https://github.com/WeshGuillaume/demo-autocomplete/blob/master/src/components/AutocompleteElements.js#L31

Comment: @RamiSalim, I'm going to dig into that

Comment: What about adding an invisible character (like a bell \x07)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and am considering trying an invisible character.

Comment: As of now adding an invisible character is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an empty character here.

```
 const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
contentStateWithEntity,
currentSelection,
`...` + '\u200A',
null,
entityKey);
```

Moreover you will have to adjust your strategy as following:

```
    function placeholderFieldStrategy(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
    (character) => {
      const entityKey = character.getEntity();
      return (
        entityKey !== null &&
        contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'PLACEHOLDER_FIELD'
      );
    },
    (start, end) => callback(start, end - 1)
  );
}
```